# BeanCreationException when Spring Data Repository extends Custom Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following repository interface:

```
public interface FooRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Foo, String>, CustomFooRepository {

}
```

And the following custom repository interface:

```
public interface CustomFooRepository {

    Flux<Foo> findFooByFilters(FooSearchParams params);
}
```

With the following implementation:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DefaultCustomFooRepository implements CustomFooRepository {

    private final ReactiveFluentMongoOperations fluentMongoOps;

    @Override
    public Flux<Foo> findFooByFilter(FooSearchParams params) {
        return fluentMongoOps
                .query(Foo.class)
                // using the received params to create a dynamic query
                .all();
    }
}
```

But the Application Context fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooRepository' defined in com.foo.fooservice.foo.FooRepository defined in @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories declared on MongoReactiveRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableReactiveMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property filter found for type Foo!
```

I used to follow this exact practice when I needed to add custom methods to a Spring Data repository and I never encountered any problems, am I doing something wrong or has the behavior changed recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.

The name of my custom repository implementation was `DefaultCustomFooRepository`.

Renaming it to `CustomFooRepositoryImpl` fixed it.

Comment: Great that you've found the problem